# Passing Arguments to a Service started with Init.d

Tags: mysql, init.d

I want to start mysql with the command argument "--log=log_file_name"

What is the proper way to do that when starting it with /etc/init.d?

Would it be like this?
/etc/init.d/mysql start --log=log_file_name

Comment: No, but that should be configured in your my.cnf, not on startup.

Comment: Well that was.. mildly helpful.  So if that's not the correct way to start it then what is?  I do NOT want it to be configured in .cnf because I don't want it to start that way everytime.

Comment: What distro is this?

Comment: it is debian 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make it simple you can create another entry in init.d to start the mysql with that logdir path option. Make a script like `/etc/init.d/mysql-log` and put following entries in it:

```
 #!/bin/sh -e
 set -e
 COMMAND=$1
 LOG="--log=/tmp/mysql.log"
 case $COMMAND in
 start)
      /etc/init.d/mysql $COMMAND $LOG
      ;;
 stop)
      /etc/init.d/mysql $COMMAND
      ;;
 restart)
      /etc/init.d/mysql stop
      /etc/init.d/mysql start $LOG
      ;;
 *)
      exit 1
 esac
```

Set the log file location in the above script as per your needs and start the mysql with the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql-log start
```

This way you can use different scripts for different occasions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass arguments to services with startup scripting.  Reason: there should be ONLY ONE argument being passed.

This argument consists of minimally only TWO choices:

```
 start     -- tells the scripting that it is being started from system startup.
 stop      -- tells the scripting that it is being STOPPED due to shutdown request
```

Trying to configure a system to pass arguments at boot time will make your system non-standard and the cause of later configuration errors.

Usually this type of adjustment is handled in the init.d scripting by setting up variables using the /etc/sysconfig/`servicename` scripting and using the '.' command to basically include them in their operation.

In otherwords, the most common process is to basically configuration files that are read-in or used by the underlying application in an init.d startup scripting.  Definitely this is NOT done via adding more arguments to this type of scripting.